# D3js: blocks with text inside & hover to show more text

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to D3js. I want to have some basic blocks like this:

[image]

The text in the block should be taken from a JSON file. If the block is hovered, it will show:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to do this? Or are there any available tutorials on this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use something with d3.select, like:

```
 .on('mouseover', function(d){
        var menuSelection = d3.select(this).style({opacity:'1.0'});
        menuSelection.select("text").style({opacity:'1.0'});
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

d3.tip()

Sorry for not being more specific (on mobile) but this example should get you what you want:

http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579